# vertex buffer renders later vertexes in front of earlier ones

Tags: c++, opengl, rendering

While trying to render a cube with OpenGL I noticed that the vertexes I defined later in my positions array rendered on top of the ones defined earlier:

[image: The depth issue]

It is hard to see in the image but if you look closely, you can see the back faces of the cube are rendering on top of the faces closest to the camera. When I move the camera to the other side of the cube it appears normally.

Do I need a check in my fragment shader to see if the face is behind others relative to the camera, and if so how do I implement it?

Comment: It is very likely that you have not activated the [Depth Test](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Depth_Test).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At first I tried enabling the depth test (I wasn't aware it was off by default) But then nothing rendered. The problem was not clearing the depth buffer every frame with glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT).

Problem Solved!